# Filtering two dimensional vector in Rust

Tags: rust

Recently started writing more rust code and interested in how anyone may get around using `.clone()` within a map of a referenced data structure. I've included a test so you can see exactly what the desired outcome is. That is, if any of the `block`s are `statement-permissions` then filter any options that are not `consent`.

```
use crate::{Block, BlockData, PermissionOption, Rule, Template};

/// # Filter options by justifications
///
/// Filters a set of options within a permissions block
/// based on it's justifications.
pub fn filter_justifications(template: &mut Template, justifications: Vec<String>) {
template.blocks = template.blocks
    .iter()
    .map(|block: &Block| -> Block {
        let Block { r#type, data } = block.clone();

        Block {
            r#type,
            data: match data {
                BlockData::StatementPermissions { id, options } => {
                    BlockData::StatementPermissions {
                        id,
                        options: options
                            .into_iter()
                            .filter(|option| {
                                justifications.contains(&option.justification)
                            })
                            .collect(),
                    }
                }
                _ => data,
            },
        }
    })
    .collect();
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
use super::*;

#[test]
fn filter_blocks_for_consents() {
    let mut template = Template {
        id: "01".to_string(),
        name: "template 01".to_string(),
        blocks: vec![
            Block {
                r#type: "preference".to_string(),
                data: BlockData::Preferences {
                    preference: "some data".to_string(),
                },
            },
            Block {
                r#type: String::from("statement-permissions"),
                data: BlockData::StatementPermissions {
                    id: "statement-01".to_string(),
                    options: vec![
                        PermissionOption {
                            option_id: "option-01".to_string(),
                            state: Some("GRANTED".to_string()),
                            justification: "consent".to_string(),
                        },
                        PermissionOption {
                            option_id: "option-02".to_string(),
                            state: None,
                            justification: "contract".to_string(),
                        },
                        PermissionOption {
                            option_id: "option-03".to_string(),
                            state: Some("DENIED".to_string()),
                            justification: "consent".to_string(),
                        },
                    ],
                },
            },
        ],
    };

    let expected = Template {
        id: "01".to_string(),
        name: "template 01".to_string(),
        blocks: vec![
            Block {
                r#type: "preference".to_string(),
                data: BlockData::Preferences {
                    preference: "some data".to_string(),
                },
            },
            Block {
                r#type: String::from("statement-permissions"),
                data: BlockData::StatementPermissions {
                    id: "statement-01".to_string(),
                    options: vec![
                        PermissionOption {
                            option_id: "option-01".to_string(),
                            state: Some("GRANTED".to_string()),
                            justification: "consent".to_string(),
                        },
                        PermissionOption {
                            option_id: "option-03".to_string(),
                            state: Some("DENIED".to_string()),
                            justification: "consent".to_string(),
                        },
                    ],
                },
            },
        ],
    };

    let rule = Rule {
        name: "block-types".to_string(),
        parameters: vec![
            "consent".to_string()
        ],
    };

    filter_justifications(&mut template, rule.parameters);

    assert_eq!(template, expected);
}
}
```

Comment: I can't test this, so please clarify: does or doesn't the current code produce the correct output?